# how to make submissions sms with SIM2 or dual SIM

Tags: android, sms, dual-sim

I created sms application android
I've been able to sms application smoothly but send by SIM 1 if i send with 2 SIM application it will error and there were no reports sent how if i want to do sms sending with 2 SIM smoothly
please help what should I add the source code of its

my code

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   Button sendBtn;
   EditText txtphoneNo;
   EditText txtMessage;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
      txtphoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
      txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

      sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
            sendSMSMessage();
         }
      });

   }
   protected void sendSMSMessage() {
      Log.i("Send SMS", "");

      String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
      String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

      try {
         SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
         smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
         "SMS faild, please try again.",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK has no support for dual-SIM devices. You will need to contact your device manufacturer to determine if and how you can send an SMS using the second SIM.

Comment: Sim Selection Option available in  Android SDK 5.1 and above