# How to send sms from dual sim phone

Tags: android, android-permissions

i have dual sim phone, used below code to send SMS

```
SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
manager.sendTextMessage(number, null, text, null, null);
```

This always send sms from first SIM card, if i deactivate first SIM card and try above code it does not send SMS only,

any idea how to overcome this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make submissions sms with SIM2 or dual SIM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728178/how-to-make-submissions-sms-with-sim2-or-dual-sim)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dual SIM card Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255147/dual-sim-card-android)

Comment: There is a way to manage sending sms with dual sim device : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30677542/2267723