# Dual Sim Sms Detection

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Hi I am developing an app where if a "LOST" message is encountered then a maximum ringtone is set.

It works perfectly for single sim phones,but not working on dual sim phone.
Here is my code

```
package com.example.ayushmnnit.yobaby;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Get the object of SmsManager
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                if(message.contains("LOST"))
                {
                    AudioManager am;

                    am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    String sp=""+am.getRingerMode();
                    Toast tte=Toast.makeText(context,sp,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    tte.show();
                    switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
                        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                          Toast st = Toast.makeText(context,"SILENT HAI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                          st.show();
                            Log.i("MyApp", "Silent mode");
                            am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 7, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES|AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
                            break;

                        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                            Toast te = Toast.makeText(context,"vibrate HAI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 7, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES|AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
                            te.show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();

            } // end for loop
        } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}
```

}

Here is the manifest file

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ayushmnnit.yobaby"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ayushmnnit.yobaby.BroadcastNewSms"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.ayushmnnit.yobaby.IncomingSms">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-  permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission> </manifest>
```

P.S.-Sorry am new to android

Comment: Well, you're logging. What logs do you get for dual sim phones?

Comment: Its does not even calls this code of IncomingSms

Comment: Maybe `intent` is null? Try logging right before `final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();`

Comment: If you have two sims, do you have to explicitly activate one of them? I've never had two sims.

Comment: Looks like it may not be supported: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19728914/2850543 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5255993/2850543

Comment: Isnt there a way to individually check sms individually of each sim?

Comment: Apparently it's not supported.

Comment: OK. I stand corrected. Dual sim support was very recently released. Like within the last month. Are you using the 5.1 SDK? http://www.androidauthority.com/android-5-1-lollipop-sdk-available-593827/

Comment: Are you able to upgrade?